# Logs not written within C# Async method that thrown an exception

Tags: c#, exception, logging, async-await, log4net

I've been assigned a bug to investigate. It is occurring within a component in one of our integration test environments. The exception thrown and logged is fairly generic, and completely unhelpful, so I set about augmenting the module with appropriate logging to help track down the source of the problem.

Once the logging code was shipped up, the test case ran, and failed as expected, and I eagerly summoned the logs. To my surprise there were none present past a particular async method call, despite the fact that I had narrowed the problem down to somewhere within this method.

```
public async Task<IResult<XmlDocument>> Handle(TrustedThirdPartyRequest request)
{
    // do stuff

    // do more stuff

    // Exception thrown after here
    Logger.Info(m => m("Someflag :{0}", someFlag));  // logs successfully

    try
    {
        if (someflagIsOn && await deriveThisThing(clientId))  //<- Exception thrown in deriveThisThing
        {
            Logger.Info(m => m("Am I called?"));  // no! I am not!
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) // super unhelpful base exception handler
    {
        Logger.Info(m => m("Unhelpful exception log"));
    }
}
```

And the method in some other class

```
private async Task<Thing> deriveThisThing(int clientId)]
{
    Logger.Info(m => m("Entered deriveThisThing"));   // <-- Line is not logged
    
    var somethingInteresting = await ThingThatThrowsException(clientId); // <-- thing throws exception

    Logger.Info(m => m("Entered deriveThisThing"));   // <-- Line is not logged

    return Thing.Whatever;
}
```

This is an API project and we're using log4net. Now, I've probably omitted a mass of further information, like logger config, etc, that is needed to answer this, but at the moment I'm hoping that there's an obvious answer to this without all of that. Any clues, folks?

Comment: When is the lambda executed? inside the method call? `Logger.Info(m => m("Someflag :{0}", someFlag));`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Good point. I had assumed it was an expression lambda, and the logger used it to pick apart the expression rather than actually execute it. But, it's an `Action<FormatMessagehandler>`. Thanks. Something to look into.

Comment: `m("Am I called? :{0}")` - the parameter for `{0}` seems to be missing

Comment: @KlausGütter, just a typo. Not relevant to this. Thanks for highlighting though. Corrected

Comment: log4net's [ILog.Info](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.ILog.Info_overloads.html) has no overload that accepts a lambda. Formatting is provided by [ILog.InfoFormat](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.ILog.InfoFormat_overloads.html). What is that `Info` method? An extension method? Naming it the same as a built-in method is a bad idea.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Looks like a bespoke wrapper. I'll dig some more. Maybe there are alternate overloads.

Comment: I would guess that your custom or extension method `Logger.Info(Action<FormatMessageHandler>()` starts something or puts something in a queue, which doesn't run to completion because the exception cancels something. Not much we can analyze without seeing that method.

Comment: Are you using `Common.Logging` perhaps? That's the library that uses FormatMessageHandler. If you want a common logging format use `Microsoft.Extension.Logging` instead. `Common.Logging` was abandoned 4 years ago when the `Microsoft.Extensions.*` classes were introduced. [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/) runs on both .NET Framework and .NET Core

Comment: Thanks all. I think I have my answer, which is "go look there". I've enquired of my colleagues as to what's going on there.

Comment: Log4Net also has its own queues that you may want to flush. Most logging systems do.